# Route protect vue-router

Tags: vue.js, jwt, authorization, vuex, vue-router

I have admin dashboard on vue and I need to know is it enouth to protect this route by checking for example "isLoggedIn" flag from vuex getters? This flag changing after success login to "true" right after client gets admin JWT from backend. If someone trying to get "/dashboard" route without that flag, vue-router forward him to "/login" route. But I still not sure about that solution: is it possible to change this flag direct from client or from vue tools?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. What is it that you're asking? Are you asking if the user of the webpage can change this flag manually?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it possible. A client with vue devtool can change the variable isLoggedIn.
I would prefer to use some kind of a list in the backend which contains the logged in admins at the moment. When someone try reaching the admin page send request to the backend to check if this user logged in as admin.